# Place a component slightly ontop of another component

Tags: css

okay so i have two components a header and a component kind of like a form and it looks like this

[image]

what i want to achieve is for the "SKAPA OYSTER" text goes abit up on the header like this.

[image]

here are the css as is today for the form part

```
.OysterView{
overflow: scroll;
height: 80vh;
width: 30vw;
position: fixed;
left: 35vw;
right:35vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

i cant seem to find anywere how i make it go partly over it.

Comment: Did you try to add z-index > z-index hedaer?

Comment: @TanDuong Yeah even if i set oysterView z-index: 1; and header -1 nothing changes

Comment: Are you able to create fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case to problem were that i didnt have an position:fixed on my header. to be able to use z-index you need an position: attribute on your element

Answer (score 0):

Well, try putting the negative margin value on oyster. Like `margin-top:-50px;` for example

Also if you are having a fixed header then it won't make much sense to overlap it with that element but that's just my opinion. However if you do wish to have a fixed header then also put `position:relative;` on oyster and `z-index:1;`